# Is it possible to stop execution of running asp program?

Tags: asp-classic

So my problem is like this...

Im doing a big query that is lasting long. When the query is running user have opportunity to stop execution from popup window.

Okay the program seems to be stopped when the user presses button in popup. But when user do another query after pressing the button, program will finish the first query and then go to a new query.

So is possible to go straight to another query?

Comment: What kinf of query? SQL? How do you "stop" the program? What do you do to abort the original query?

Comment: I mean that i had to terminate the execution of program.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of OCI API that does it, but not sure if its available for C# (ASP as u mentioned). The only option is to kill that process.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to kill an individual running process in iis other than killing the whole iis by doing iisreset /restart in cmd on the server

only other solutions would be to do - server.scripttimeout = 120

120 is the number of seconds - 90 secs is default

or in case of SQL, you can do conn.commandtimeout = 30 where conn is your connection variable

or if you have the facility of 2 servers, I would run the 2nd query on a 2nd server and then 3rd on - 1st and then so on.